# Convert JSON String to an associative Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have problems to access to an array in Javascript which I converted from a JSON String.

This is the code:

```
var data = "{"2":"value1", "3":"value2", "4":"value4"}";
var result = JSON.parse(data);
```

My question is: How I can acces to the values? Suppose I want obtain "value1", how I can acces to it?

Regards

Comment: Not a valid string, escape your double quotes inside `"{\"2\":\"value1\",...}";`

Comment: Your `data` string is not a valid string, and the content of the string is not an array

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your outer quotes. Also, the best way to get an "associative array" where you have associated keys that are strings other than positive numbers is with an object, which JSON.parse returns to you anyway.

```js
var data = '{"2":"value1", "3":"value2", "4":"value4"}'; // outer quotes converted to single quotes
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(result["2"]);  // "value1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a solution in pure **Javascript:**

```js
var data = '{"2":"value1", "3":"value2", "4":"value4"}';
var result = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(result["2"]);
```

Now here's a solution using **jQuery**. Hope it helps

```js
var data = '{"2":"value1", "3":"value2", "4":"value4"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(obj["2"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "{\"2\":\"value1\", \"3\":\"value2\", \"4\":\"value4\"}";
var result = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(result["2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "{\"2\":\"value1\", \"3\":\"value2\", \"4\":\"value4\"}";
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.table(result);
// Object
//     2: "value1"
//     3: "value2"
//     4: "value4"
```

You can now access them like you normally would in an object:

```
console.log(result["2"]);  // "value1"
console.log(result["3"]);  // "value2"
console.log(result["4"]);  // "value4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although escaping quotes is a solution for your issue, it is easier if you use single quotes for the JavaScript string literal:

```js
var data = '{"2":"value1", "3":"value2", "4":"value4"}';
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(result);
```